# Class member variables never getting initialized in new class

Tags: c++, class, variables, header-files

I have a program that when a class calls a function from another class to access or change its member variables nothing happens. Even if I were to call a setName("John") function and then try to get the name later on with an getName() function the string returns empty, same with all other variable types. 
Is there something wrong with my class functions? I'm new to c++ and this is the first time ive used multiple header and class files in a program so little things like this tend to get me..

This is my first header class:

```
class Customer{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string adress;
    long socialSecurity;
    float interstRate;
    float balance;
    string accountType;

public:
    Customer(){
        this->firstName = "";
        this->lastName = "";
        this->adress = "";
        this->socialSecurity = 0;
        this->interstRate = 0.0;
        this->balance = 0.0;
        this->accountType = "";
    };
    Customer(string first, string last, string adrs, long sociNum, float rate, float bal, string type){
        this->firstName = first;
        this->lastName = last;
        this->adress = adrs;
        this->socialSecurity = sociNum;
        this->interstRate = rate;
        this->balance = bal;
        this->accountType = type;
    };

public:
    void updateBalance();
    void setName(string first, string last);
    string getFirstName();
    string getLastName();
    void setAdress(string adrs);
    //other methods omitted to preserve length
};
```

Second header:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.h"

class Bank{
public:
    void createAccount( Customer );
    void printAccount( vector<Customer>&, int );
    void print_ALL_Acounts( vector<Customer>& );
    int search( vector<Customer>&);
};
```

Example of a function inside the bank class:

```
void Bank::createAccount(Customer newCust){
    string first, last, adress, accountT;
    long ssn;
    float rate, balance;

    cout<< "Please Specify A First And Last Name: ";
    cin>> first >> last;
    newCust.setName(first, last);

    cout<< "Please Specify An Adress: ";
    getline(cin, adress);
    cout << endl;
    newCust.setAdress(adress);

    cout<< "Please Specify A Social Security Number: ";
    cin>> ssn;
    newCust.setSocialSecurity(ssn);

    cout<< "Please Specify An Account Type: ";
    cin>> accountT;
    newCust.setAccountT(accountT);

    cout<< "Please Specify An Interest Rate: ";
    cin>> rate;
    newCust.setInterest(rate);

    cout<< "Please Specify An Account Balance: ";
    cin>> balance;
    newCust.setBalance(balance);
}
```

Example of functions in the customer class:

```
void Customer::updateBalance()
{
    balance = balance*interstRate;
}
void Customer::setName(string first, string last){
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
}
string Customer::getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
string Customer::getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}
void Customer::setAdress(string adrs){
    adress = adrs;
}
```

And last, this is how I would call them in the main class:

```
Bank bank;
Customer account;
vector<Customer> accountList;

bank.createAccount(account);
accountList.push_back(account);
```

And then if I would go to print the list of accounts I created they would all turn up with empty values.
So based off of this can anyone point and and explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the entire `createAccount` function. What you posted doesn't show what you are going to do with `newCust`. It is important you show this, because right now, it is a local (temporary) that will just go out of scope once the function exits.

Comment: The rest of that function follows the same format, its basically just a big mutator function, it just asks for the rest of the values that you don't see there and sets them, it doesn't do anything after that! The two answers below fixed the problem I just have to wait till the thread is 15 minutes old to mark one of their comments as the the answer! Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: The answers below are related to my comment. You passed the variable by value, meaning that the parameter is a temporary that is local to the function. If you had, for example, copied `newCust` to a global vector or some other container before the return, then the "pass-by-value" wouldn't be an issue. That's why it was important to show the rest of the code, to see exactly whether you were going to copy `newCust` somewhere before the `createAccount` function returned.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now, sorry for the misconception! I updated it to the complete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `account` to `createAccount`, you are passing it by value. That means that you are copying it into the function and modifying the copy. The `account` variable that you passed is left unmodified.

For now, a simple solution is to pass the `Customer` by reference:

```
void Bank::createAccount(Customer& newCust);
```

A reference type (with `&`) allows you to modify the original object that was passed to the function.

However, I would only consider this a temporary solution, because it looks like your architecture is a bit strange. I would expect the `Bank` to keep track of the `accountList` (as a member), and then `createAccount` would do `push_back` at the end.

Also, think about your naming convention. I was confused to see a `Customer` variable called `account`. And "address" is spelt with two Ds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `Customer` instance by reference to get the values properly set

```
void Bank::createAccount(Customer& newCust) { 
                              // ^
    // ...
}
```

same for other places maybe.

Otherwise you're changing just a copy made of the `Customer` instance on the stack of this function. The original will stay unchanged.